# Reactjs: How to use Window.postMessage() from window.open() to my parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to communicate with my window.open() with my parent page with a simple "Test done" post message.
I have gone through some examples as well but not sure how to replicate it here.

Any suggestion what I can do here to make it possible.

//homepage

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

handleTestVisibleClick = () => {
    const testUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/test.html";

    document.getElementsByClassName('connect-dialog')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';

    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    var width = 410;
    var height = 460;
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 10);
    var windowOpen = window.open(testUrl, "Window2",
    "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left="
    + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY="
    + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");

  
    var timer = setInterval(function() { 
      if(windowOpen.closed) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          document.getElementsByClassName('connect-media-dialog')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    }, 100);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <dialog open={open} className="section">
          <Button  className="connect-test-button"
            onClick={()=>{ this.handleTestVisibleClick() }}>
            Test
          </Button>
          
      </dialog>
    ); 

  }
};

export default HomePage;
```

//testpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Device</title>
    <script>
      function testdone() {
          self.close();
          window.opener.postMessage("Test Done", '*');
      }
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
<button onclick="testdone()"> End Test </button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to create a sandbox or add your component where this dialog toggle is set?

Comment: Hi @Dax thanks for your time.. I ahev just fihure this out with 
`document.getElementsByClassName('connect-media-dialog')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';`

Comment: @Dax but if I want to postmessage from my window.open()... to my homepage... how it can be done... Any suggestion.

Comment: can you update your question with your current code? And what do you mean with post message from window?

Comment: I mean to say cross-origin Window.postMessage()

Comment: @Dax I think he means this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 yes my bad yes you are right. Any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by accessing the child window's `postMessage` property.

```js
var child = window.open('https://www.example.com')

child.postMessage('something')
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8850s/ev1xj8uc/

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer but here in my case from window.open(Url) ... It should post a message back to parent component thatt test is done.

Comment: @Tammy Is this what you're trying to do? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Example

Comment: yes kind of same... In my test url there is a test done button.  So wheneve test done button is clicked it should post a message a back to parent .

Comment: @Tammy You could just listen for a click and then run a function.

Comment: could you please guide me with my code. not too much have idea with such case.

Comment: `<button onClick={functionToRun}> postMessage </button>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221327/discussion-between-tammy-and-galaxycat105).